# Angle help in a Java

Tags: java, trigonometry, angle

I'm trying to make an angle program that calculates the sin, cos and tan of an inputted angle. Here's the part of the code that I have a problem with :

```
c.println ("You have entered an angle of " + angle + " degrees.");
radians = Math.toRadians (angle); //convert angle (which is in degrees) to radians(radians = (pi / 180)*degrees)
c.println ("The angle in radians is " + radians); //diplay angle in radians

//caluclating sine, cosine & tangent

double sinx = Math.sin (Math.toRadians (angle));
c.println ("The sine of the angle is " + sinx+ " radians."); //convert sin of angle (in deg) to radians
double cosx = Math.cos (Math.toRadians (angle));
c.println ("The cosine of the angle is " + cosx+ " radians.");//convert cos of angle (in deg) to radians
double tanx = Math.tan (Math.toRadians (angle));
c.println ("The tangent of the angle is " + tanx+ " radians.");//convert tan of angle (in deg) to radians
```

If I enter an angle of 90 degrees, the cosine output is 6.12^-17.... when it should just = 0. So there's a calculation error somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean by `There's an error in the code`?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What's some sample input and output? Also, be aware that radians is from 0-6.28..., not 0-2.

Comment: `"The ... of the angle is ... radians."` - Not sure whether the print message is incorrect, or your understanding is, but the `sin`/`cos`/`tan` of an angle doesn't return a number in radians. `sin` and `cos` is `[-1,1]`, `tan` is `[-Inf, Inf]`. See [this](http://www.mathsrevision.net/gcse/sincostan.gif).

Comment: I tried it and checked it with my calculator, and it outputs everything like it should. I don't see any error.

Comment: If I enter an angle of 90 degrees, the cosine output is 6.12^-17.... when it should just = 0. So there's a calculation error somewheree? Here are my output results if I enter an angle of 90.

Answer (score -1):

It's just a rounding error. The number is really small so if you round it to 14 decimal places or just output the first 15 places it will equal 0. The conversion from degrees to radians isn't exact so it gives a value very close to 0 but not exactly. You can't actually store the exact value of PI for obvious reasons.